# Need PHP / Laravel OAuth2 client example

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

I am attempting to set up my site as a client with an oauth2 server from another company. I am using the Laravel PHP framework and it occurred to me that there is surely a simpler way of doing this outside of writing each line of code myself and then wondering if everything is done correctly. Is there a tutorial on this somewhere?

Again, I don't want to set up my site as the server, just as the client.

Thanks